# Is reaching perfect performance on the training set feasible for large neural networks in regression?

Tags: neural-networks, optimization

Suppose I have a large training sample, say a million observations, and want to perform regression with a large ReLU-activated neural network (both deep and wide, with many times more parameters than the sample size). In principle, it should be possible to interpolate the training data and achieve perfect performance (or at least perfect up to some very tiny "numerical error"). I'm wondering whether it's feasible in practice to find such an interpolating network by training the network. Is this something that is practically feasibly, say by performing SGD with square loss for a long time and with many random initializations? Or is this way too computationally expensive in large-scale cases like this, and we need to be satisfied with some non-zero training loss?

What about the case where the neural network has less parameters than the sample size? Or the case where we have more parameters, but we restrict the number of non-zero parameters being less than the sample size (ie, sparsity)?

I know about the potential overfitting issue, but I'm interested in this more out of theoretical curiosity.

Comment: Not in general. You can easily have two instances in your training data with precisely the same predictor values but different outcomes. Your network will give the same fit for both, so at least one will necessarily be different from the true outcome.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. Suppose that a neural network with  perfect fit does exist. Is it then usually the case that we can find it using optimization methods, or is that often too computationally expensive for large samples and large networks?